# Parsing a list using java streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

My usecase is I have list of Restaurants objects with attributes as city, type, rating and I want to print the list by highest rating for given combination of (city, type). As I created this example to mess with java stream, please reply how it can be achieved using streams:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.maxBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import static java.util.Comparator.comparingLong;

class Restaurant {
  public String city; // Any city
  public String type; // Tier1, Tier2, etc. 
  public Long rating; // for simplicity sake, assume its a number from 1 to 5
  public Restaurant(String city, String type, Long rating) { 
    this.city = city;
    this.type = type;
    this.rating = rating;
  }
  public String getCity() { return city; }
  public String getType() { return type; }
  public Long getRating() { return rating; }
}

public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    List<Restaurant> mylist = new ArrayList<Restaurant>();
    mylist.add(new Restaurant("City1", "Tier1", 1L));
    mylist.add(new Restaurant("City1", "Tier1", 2L));
    mylist.add(new Restaurant("City1", "Tier2", 1L));
    mylist.add(new Restaurant("City2", "Tier1", 1L));
    mylist.add(new Restaurant("City2", "Tier1", 3L));
    mylist.add(new Restaurant("City2", "Tier3", 1L));
    // expected outcome: (City1, Tier1, 2), (City1, Tier2, 1), (City2, Tier1, 3), (City2, Tier3, 1)

    Map<String, Map<String, Optional<Restaurant>>> mymap =
   mylist.stream().collect(groupingBy(Restaurant::getCity, groupingBy(Restaurant::getType, maxBy(comparingLong(Restaurant::getRating)))));
   /* Upto here everything is fine, but I want to have everything stored back into a list. Tried flatMap(Map::values).collect(Collectors.toList()); but it fails*/
  /*My output list should have 4 objects of Restaurant*/
  /*(City1, Tier1, 2), (City1, Tier2, 1), (City2, Tier1, 3), (City2, Tier3, 1)*/
  }
}
```

Comment: I edited your question to clarify it. Also I fixed the expected output. Please check whether my edit meets your intentions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you can create composite key to get rid of nested maps. The `Arrays.asList(r.getCity(), r.getType())` is what you need. Next, `groupingBy` is not well suitable in your case, as you should handle those nasty optionals. Instead use `toMap` collector with custom merging function:

```
Map<List<String>, Restaurant> mymap = mylist.stream().collect(
        toMap(r -> Arrays.asList(r.getCity(), r.getType()), r -> r,
                BinaryOperator.maxBy(comparingLong(Restaurant::getRating))));
```

Now `mymap.values()` is the flat collection of restaurants as you want. If you really want the `List`, you can dump it into one:

```
List<Restaurant> list = new ArrayList<>(mymap.values());
```

Comment: As your solution is the most elegant one, this is my accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

The code snippet below should produce the result you are after:

```
    List<Optional<Restaurant>> resultList = mymap.values()
                                                 .stream()
                                                 .flatMap(map -> map.values().stream())
                                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

`mymap.values().stream()` produces a `Stream<Map<String, Optional<Restaurant>>>`. `flatMap()` then maps that stream to a `Stream<Optional<Restaurant>>`, and `collect(Collectors.toList())` collects that stream into a `List<Optional<Restaurant>>`.

Comment: Works perfectly, exactly what I wanted and appreciate the explanation

Answer (score -1):

I haven't worked with Java 8 yet but my guess is

```
mylist.stream().sorted(new Comparator<Restaurant>() {
     public int compare(Restaurant r1, Restaurant r2) {
        // impl here how your restaurant should be compared
        // (by rating or smth. else)
     }
}).collect(groupingBy( .../ al the rest stuff here/ ...));
```

Answer (score -2):

using Java 8 stream API:

```
List<Restaurant> sortedList = mylist.stream()
.sorted((restaurant1, restaurant2) -> Long.compare(restaurant1.getRating(), restaurant2.getRating()))
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: can someone explain to me why the downvote? imo, the code fragment gives a complete answer to the question

Comment: I didnt downvote, but in general your solution is not correct, as it is comparing just the ratings and do not take care if the city and type is same or not. e.g. it produces list as follows: City1, Tier1, 1
City1, Tier2, 1
City2, Tier1, 1
City2, Tier3, 1

Comment: @sharonbn, downvote is issued by me. You did not read the question to the end and your solution is incorrect. This seems enough reason to downvote.